# Importing shapefile into R

Tags: shapefile, r

I don't understand why I should choose `readOGR()` over `readShapePoly`.

What are all the different ways of doing this, and why should I choose one over another?

Comment: Could you edit your question and describe what you have tried so far, and what your needs for shapefiles are?

Comment: If you read the [help file](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/maptools/versions/0.9-5/topics/readShapePoly) for R is says readShapePoly is deprecated and don't use, use readOGR(), so I think your question is obsolete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is explained in the documentation for maptools::readShapePoly, which you should read when asking questions of a function:

```
Description:

     The use of this function is deprecated and it is not being
     maintained. Use ‘rgdal::readOGR()’ or ‘sf::st_read()’ instead -
     both of these read the coordinate reference system from the input
     file, while this deprecated function does not.For writing, use
     ‘rgdal::writeOGR()’ or ‘sf::st_write()’ instead.
```

The difference between `rgdal::readOGR` and `sf::st_read` is that they create very different R objects to store the information in the shapefile, and functions from one package are incompatible with data from the other.

You may also find people using `raster::shapefile` to read shapefiles, this is a convenience wrapper so instead of doing `readOGR("/data/maplibrary/world","countries")` you do `shapefile("/data/maplibrary/world/countries.shp")` - ie you specify the path to the `.shp` file in one argument and not split into folder and shapefile name.